# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.main

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, apache-nifi, loggerfactory

i use intellij idea to run the nifi source code from bootstrap/.../RunNiFi.main("start"): [github link](https://github.com/apache/nifi), but it get wrong like this: [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw4rL.png)

can you help me ?

thanks

and should i run the code from bootstrap/.../RunNiFi.main("start")?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to launch a single Java class from your IDE to start NiFi, the classpath won't be setup correctly.

You'll need to run a full build and get the assembly from nifi-assembly/target and then run NiFi from the built assembly by using "bin/nifi.sh start".

You can run it directly from the unpacked assembly target, for example:

```
cd nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT
./bin/nifi.sh start
```

EDIT: You can still use debugger, but it will be debugging a remote Java application. In NiFi's bootstrap.conf, uncomment the following line and restart NiFi:

```
#java.arg.debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

This tells the NiFi JVM to listen for incoming debug requests on port 8000.

In your IDE, create a Remote debugging configuration and connect to localhost port 8000. Your break points should work like normal.

Comment: thank you very much, but i want to run nifi step by step, and set break points, i want to read the codes, could you tell me how could i do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you can read chinese, you can read my personal blog [link here](https://user.qzone.qq.com/353688193/blog/1522837266)

I found the methods,
if you want remote debug nifi, please follow [remote debug link](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/106931/nifi-debugging-tutorial.html).

if you want local debug, you can follow bellow.
(I used Intellij idea in windows to debug)

1.

`$ git config --global core.longpaths true
$ git config --global core.autocrlf false`

2. open intellij idea to git clone https://github.com/apache/nifi,
   [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSNXN.png), 
   set the import configure as default, next...
   after opened the project, the nifi may get wrong message, just ignore it.
3. mvn -T 2 clean install -DskipTests
4. configure debugger
   [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RijVD.png), 
   [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKfVR.png)

> acknowledge:

nifi quick start link: https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html

Running NiFi in Debug mode link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Contributor+Guide#ContributorGuide-RunningNiFiinDebugmode